# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet to existing file Not Working

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have the following code:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm"), sFileLocation & sFileName
```

where `sFileLocation` is my desktop and `sFileName` is Temp.xlsx

The excel file acts as if it has been modified (the date/time modified changes), but when you open it, the data is not there. There are queries for all months of the year in the database, and all of the queries return data, so that is not the problem. If I change Temp.xlsx to Temp1.xlsx (which does not exist), the data exports with no problem.

Any ideas on why the data is not exporting to an existing file.

Comment: Check to see whether a new worksheet is created within the existing XLSX workbook file.

Comment: @HansUp -- That was actually the end goal we were looking for, to have a new worksheet created within the existing XLSX. If worked for 6 worksheets, but once we got to seven, it stopped working.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize what you're dealing with.  So this month you're exporting a table or query named "June", and you can export "June" to the same XLSX file successfully 6 times, but attempting to export "June" a seventh time fails with no error message.  Is that correct now?

Comment: Do you intentionally want to export as XML?
I've had similar issues and they work when I replace `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` with `10` and exclude the .xlsx at at the end of the file name. like this
`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport,10, Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm"), sFileLocation & filename`